# Charateristric Polynomial Related

Tags: matrices, determinant

How to find value of $\lambda$ for following determinant by applying suitable row and column operation?

$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda-4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
0 & \lambda-5 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & \lambda-4 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda-4 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda-4 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda-3 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \lambda-2 
\end{pmatrix}=0$

Comment: How is it equal to $0$? Did you mean to write the determinant of your matrix is equal to $0$?

Comment: Actually I am working with eigen values of a matrix and this matrix is one of part of simplification

Comment: Ah, I see now that you indeed meant the determinant is $0$, sorry for the confusion. Perhaps you could change the pmatrix to a vmatrix, but it is up to you.